# combine like lists withing a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

i have a large nested list, and with in each nested list are two values, a company name and an amount, i am wondering if there is a way to combine the nested lists that have the same name together and then add the values? so for example here is a section of the list

```
[['Acer', 481242.74], ['Beko', 966071.86], ['Cemex', 187242.16], ['Datsun', 748502.91], ['Equifax', 146517.59], ['Gerdau', 898579.89], ['Haribo', 265333.85], ['Gerdau', 13019.63676], ['Gerdau', 34107.12062], ['Acer', 52153.02848]
```

i would expect an outcome that looks like the one below

```
[['Acer',(481242.74+52153.02848)],['Beko', 966071.86],['Cemex', 187242.16],['Datsun', 748502.91],['Equifax', 146517.59],['Gerdau',(898579.89+13019.63676+34107.12062)],['Haribo', 265333.85]]
```

so essentially im trying to write a code that will go through a nested list and return a list made by finding all the lists with the same [0] element and combining there [1] element

Comment: "so essentially im trying to write a code"... Then show what you've tried please.

Answer (score 4):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(float)
for name, amt in a:
    d[name] += amt
```

What this does is to create a dict where the amount will be zero (`float()`) by default, and then sum up using the names as keys.

If you really need the result to be a list, you can get it this way:

```
>>> print d.items()
[('Equifax', 146517.59), ('Haribo', 265333.85), ('Gerdau', 945706.64738), ('Cemex', 187242.16), ('Datsun', 748502.91), ('Beko', 966071.86), ('Acer', 533395.76848)]
```

Comment: You can literally copy paste it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
l=[['Acer', 481242.74], ['Beko', 966071.86], ['Cemex', 187242.16], ['Datsun', 748502.91], ['Equifax', 146517.59], ['Gerdau', 898579.89], ['Haribo', 265333.85], ['Gerdau', 13019.63676], ['Gerdau', 34107.12062], ['Acer', 52153.02848]]
for k,v in l:
    d[k].append(v)
w=[]
for x,y in d.items():
    w.append([x,sum(y)])
print w
```

Prints-

```
[['Equifax', 146517.59], ['Haribo', 265333.85], ['Gerdau', 945706.64738], ['Cemex', 187242.16], ['Datsun', 748502.91], ['Beko', 966071.86], ['Acer', 533395.76848]]
```

If want to make it a tuple

```
map(tuple,w)
```

Output is-

```
[('Equifax', 146517.59), ('Haribo', 265333.85), ('Gerdau', 945706.64738), ('Cemex', 187242.16), ('Datsun', 748502.91), ('Beko', 966071.86), ('Acer', 533395.76848)]
```

Comment: This doesn't "add" the values mathematically, rather it adds them to a list.  I think the OP using `+` instead of `,` means he/she wants math.

Answer (score 0):

`defaultdict` is probably a good way to go but you can do this with a normal dictionary:

```
>>> data = [['Acer', 481242.74], ['Beko', 966071.86], ['Cemex', 187242.16], ...]
>>> result = {}
>>> for k, v in data:
...     result[k] = result.get(k, 0) + v
>>> result
{'Acer': 533395.76848, 'Beko': 966071.86, 'Cemex': 187242.16, ... }
>>> list(result.items())
[('Acer', 533395.76848), ('Beko', 966071.86), ('Cemex', 187242.16), ...]
```